# libvlc_video_set_mouse_input do not work while playing

Tags: c++, libvlc

I'm trying to play DVD with `libvlc`, I use `libvlc_video_set_mouse_input`, and `libvlc_video_set_key_input` to enable or disable key press and mouse click events handling, but they do not work when I called these to APIs while the DVD playing. Could anybody tell me why, and how to make it works?

I set `libvlc_video_set_mouse_input (_vlcMediaPlayer,true)`when the DVD menu is shown, but when the DVD movie is playing I should set `libvlc_video_set_mouse_input (_vlcMediaPlayer,false)`, because I want to get mouse click event in my app.it doesn't work.

Comment: I set  libvlc_video_set_mouse_input (_vlcMediaPlayer,true)when the DVD menu is shown,but,when the DVD movie is playing I should set  libvlc_video_set_mouse_input (_vlcMediaPlayer,false),because I want to get mouse click event in my app.it doesn't work